# how to test MQTT server in ubuntu?

Tags: server, mosquitto

I have installed the MQTT server 'mosquitto' in my ubuntu machine by following the instructions in this link https://lukeisadog.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/setting-up-mqtt-on-ubuntu-round-1/ . But I am not able to test the server. When I type `mosquitto` in command prompt I am getting below error.

```
 1431416111: mosquitto version 1.4.2 (build date 2015-05-09  21:39:32+0000) starting
 1431416111: Using default config.
 1431416111: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1431416111: Error: Address already in use
```

when i type `mosquitto –daemon –verbose` I am getting error like "Unknown option '–daemon'".
Please help me on this.

Comment: Make sure that 1883 port is not used by any other process(netstat to check) or change the port in mosquitto config file in may be /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf some thing  like "**port 1884**"

Answer (score 8):

If you have install mosquitto from the repository, it will have started automatically for you. Try connecting with e.g.

```
mosquitto_sub -t '$SYS/#' -v
```

You may need to install the `mosquitto-clients` package first.

If this works, you already have an instance of mosquitto running. If you want to run the broker manually yourself, you can stop the automatically started instance with `sudo stop mosquitto`.

With regards to the unknown option, you should note that you need two dashes, so `--daemon`, not `-daemon`.